# Get Result from a mySQL DB table by matching a id in another table (plus) little authentication

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am doing a simple project where I take **StudentID** & **DateOfBirth** from the user and give them their exam result. Now I have two tables.

Table **user** having field

- UserID
- DateOfBirth

& **result** having rows

- UserID
- sub1Marks
- sub2Marks
- sub3Marks

Now, I need to ask the users their ID and Date of Birth and match it from both the columns and display the results.

Please help me out !

Comment: learn [`Join`](https://www.google.com.kw/search?q=join+mysql&rlz=1C5CHFA_enKW503KW503&oq=join+mysql&aqs=chrome.0.57j0l3j62l2.4315j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)... you will get answer your-self..

Comment: SELECT t2.* FROM `user` t1 LEFT JOIN `result` t2 ON (t1.UserID = t2.UserId) WHERE t1.DateOfBirth = [you insert dateofbirth here] AND t1.UserID= [you insert UserID here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you need to do a table join.

```
select table2.sub1Marks, table2.sub2marks, table2.sub3marks, table2.userId
from <tablename2> table2 inner join <tablename1> table1
on table2.userId = table1.userId
where table1.userID = <userid> and
table1.DateOfBirth = <DOB>
```

Though before posting your question try researching it for you. What you are doing is the bread and button of SQL and you really should try and learn it otherwise you will struggle with everything else.

Comment: Thank You. I did research and came across this but wasn't sure if this was the solution or I was missing something...

Comment: I find it strange that when I perform this at phpMyAdmin interface I get the correct result but the php side is giving me a troll.

Answer (score 0):

Use this SQL:

```
SELECT r.sub1Marks, r.sub2Marks, r.sub3Marks 
FROM results r 
INNER JOIN user u 
    ON u.userID = r.UserID 
        AND u.UserID = [users ID]
        AND u.DateOfBirth = [users Date of Birth]
```

Obviously replace `[users ID]` and `[users Date of Birth]` with the data the user submits.